# Rendered image/video loses material and lighting

Tags: rendering

The blender model when rendered as an image or animation through the top menu bar doesn't display most material and light elements. (image 1)

Although when viewing the model thought the view-port at the bottom of the stage as a render preview, it show all the correct lighting and material elements. (image 2)

I can't seem to find the setting/s to enable all materials and lighting effects to be displayed during rendering via the top menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Managed to find the issue.

Under the render layers tab, there is a material override option, that replaces all materials with only one. My issue was fixed when clearing this material option.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Newer versions of blender don't use layers, but "collections" so the override function is in the scene>View Layer section.

[image]

Additional info:

[Where is the Layers panel in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/where-is-the-layers-panel-in-blender-2-8/96465#96465)

[2.8 - Is it possible to assign (override) a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)