# Where is the Layers panel in Blender 2.8?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, layers

I am starting working on Blender 2.8, but I can't find the layer panel. Where is it?

[image]

Comment: There are no more bit layers in 2.8

Comment: Well, the missing layer panel is to stay, it is unlikely to re-appear in official 2.8, so I would squint eyes here and wouldn't count the dev version argument.. This question is likely to be applicable to many people when 2.8 becomes reality..

Comment: You are right, this one does have value in the long run. Retracting vote

Answer (score 19):

Blender 2.8 re-implements the scene layer system, as it had limitations. How it now works is explained here: [Layers Manual](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Layers) and here: [Blender Dev blog](https://code.blender.org/2017/09/view-layers-and-collections/).

The scene layers are gone and their functionality was implemented in *Collections* (=groups) and *View Layers*.

Instead of sorting objects onto different scene layers, you can sort them into different Collections.

- *Add* and *Move* between Collections with <kbd>M</kbd>
- *Link* to Collection with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (so an object can be in multiple Collections)
- *Hide* and *Unhide* Collections with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

Instead of using scene layers as masking layers in Render layers, now you can use Collections for masking or to effect only indirect rays (shadows and reflections):

[image]

View Layers are what you would call Render layers pre-2.8-Blender. Add them here:

[image]

A View Layer will remember your settings of objects and collections for visibility in view and render, selectability, holdout and indirect-only, etc. You find the settings for View Layers in the Properties panel:

[image]

Comment: Just a reminder to update now...

Comment: @JakeD thx! edited

Comment: Thank you! This saved me.

Comment: what about the LOD trick that you could do for unity? : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifNyVS2_6f8 how do you do that now?

Comment: @tatsu I think having different LODs on different view layers was irrelevant for the export. Just for convenience to view them better so they don't overlap.

Comment: Yeah I figured out through trial and error that the minimal requirement for it to work was for the parent mesh to have the `_LODn` perpend and whether or not you have a Collection is completely irrelevant. it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Collection center icon in the scene menu (top right) which hides the current collection. Add a new collection and work there.