# Render only has gray textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

The "rendered" viewport in the editor shows my model just fine.

[image]But once I actually render it it doesnt render the materials with it, instead everything has a gray texture.
It doesnt render any lighting either.

[image]

I am using the cycles renderer.

Here are the nodes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are for lighting. The render looks the same with them enabled.

Comment: Is the output section in the render panel set to "rgb" or "bw" ?

Comment: Its set to rgba

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Please add an image that shows the nodes you used for the material.

Comment: Did you assign the material to the faces of your object? Read: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: I did it exactly like the link says

Comment: Heres the link to my .blend file: https://ufile.io/wnc3z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a material override set in your Scene>Layer panel. (Where it says 'Material'). Hit the cross in there to deactivate it.

[image: Material Override]

**EDIT:**

Newer versions of blender don't use layers, but "collections" so the override function is in the scene>View Layer section.

[image]

Additional info:

[Where is the Layers panel in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/where-is-the-layers-panel-in-blender-2-8/96465#96465)

[2.8 - Is it possible to assign (override) a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)