# Blender Internal - colorless render (no materials)

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I downloaded a model from BlenderSwap - https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/88280 - but when I render it the result is almost colorless but not quite (so I am pretty sure it is not greyscale, although have double checked the render settings and they are on RGBA

[image]

One of the materials in the model called Clay does seem to be this color but most of the faces are assigned the yellow or green materials which show up fine ... until it is rendered.

There are no textures in use so it can't be missing external files.

I've compared my render settings with other blender files that work and they seem identical.

What am I missing?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your Render Layers settings - this includes an option to override the material for all objects in the scene :

[image: blender internal render layers material override]

If set, Blender will render all meshes with the specified material.

**EDIT:**

Newer versions of blender don't use layers, but "collections" so the override function is in the scene>View Layer section.

[image]

Additional info:

[Where is the Layers panel in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/where-is-the-layers-panel-in-blender-2-8/96465#96465)

[2.8 - Is it possible to assign (override) a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)

Comment: Thank you! Yet another hidden away option I've now learnt about!