# Clay render linked objects in 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, linked-data

I have a scene full of linked objects from other blender files. How do I clay render the scene with linked objects in blender 2.80?

Comment: Basically give the objects a default texture, and enable clay rendering.

Comment: How do you enable clay rendering in 2.8?

Comment: In Blender preferences, go to the render addons, and enable *clay rendering*

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection

Comment: hey, thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this without any addon.
Just use the *Material Override* option in Cycles.
It will render all objects with the selected material.

1) Create your Clay material.
2) Select it in the *Material Override* panel.
3) Select how many samples you want to render (0 will use the scene settings)

*Material Override with a material selected.*
[image]

*Material Override* currently works in Cycles only, Eevee doesn't support this feature.