# Switch off materials

Tags: rendering, materials

When I click on viewport shading (render), it first goes into a monotone (i.e. without materials) for a few seconds before the materials show up. (It's a big model with lots of trees, so it takes a few seconds to process.) I actually quite like the monotone effect as I can study the lighting better this way. Is there a way to switch off all the materials so that when I click on viewport shading, it will just be monotone?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). This looks like a simple wireframe view. You can easily render it from viewport.

Comment: @JachymMichal but there's only front geometry visible there 

Comment: @Markus True, good point :)

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure, whether you want this, but you can achieve this with compositing like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For cycles, you could refer to this answer about overriding all materials:  [2.8 - Is it possible to assign (override) a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)

Alternatively, you could choose the Workbench engine and set "Color" to a "Single" Gray (or whatever you like) and enable shadows.
[image]